# How to get python via virtual environment recognized in bash file via shebang

Tags: python, bash

I have a script file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.9

print("python is working")
```

However when I try and run it:

```
(karl-env) karl@Karls-MBP scripts (karl/test) $ . test.sh 
bash: test.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `"python is working"'
bash: test.sh: line 3: `print("python is working")'
```

Following info:

```
(karl-env) karl@Karls-MBP scripts (karl/test) $ type -a python
python is /Users/karl/.pyenv/shims/python
python is /Users/karl/.pyenv/shims/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

I'm in a virtual environment but I fail to understand how to get my environments python recognized via the shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python3.9`. I do not use Python often hence my noobiness!

Comment: You have a space instead of a slash in the command line. Voting to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

This has a little to do with Python and a lot to do with the shell.

1. You're doing `. test.sh` – [`.` is an alias for `source`](https://superuser.com/questions/46139/what-does-source-do), which has your shell attempt to interpret the given script as shell commands you'd enter. You want `./test.sh` to execute the script.
2. Your shebang line is explicitly looking for a `python3.9` executable, and your environment might not be Python 3.9, so you fall back to something else. Do `python` (or `python3`) instead: `#!/usr/bin/env python`
3. For the sake of sanity, rename your script to `.py`; it's not a `.sh`ellscript.